# finding all unique words from a list using loops

Tags: python, list, loops, python-2.7, iterator

I'm trying to make a list of unique words based on a list of all words taken from a text file.  My only issue is the algorithm used to iterate over both lists.

```
def getUniqueWords(allWords):
    uniqueWords = []
    uniqueWords.append(allWords[0])
    for i in range(len(allWords)):
        for j in range(len(uniqueWords)):
            if allWords[i] == uniqueWords[j]:
                pass
            else:
                uniqueWords.append(allWords[i])
                print uniqueWords[j]
    print uniqueWords
    return uniqueWords
```

as you can see I made an empty list and began iterating over both lists.  Also, I appended the first item in the list because for some reason it wouldn't attempt to try and match the words I assume. After all, in an empty list, list[0] does not exist.  if anyone can help me figure out how to properly iterate over this such that I can generate a list of words that would be great.

the print uniqueWords[j] was just to debug so I could see what was coming out during the processing of the list

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not a python expert but think this should work:

```
uniqueWords = [] 
for i in allWords:
      if not i in uniqueWords:
          uniqueWords.append(i);

return uniqueWords
```

**EDIT:**

I tested and it works, it returns only unique words from a list:

```
def getUniqueWords(allWords) :
    uniqueWords = [] 
    for i in allWords:
        if not i in uniqueWords:
            uniqueWords.append(i)
    return uniqueWords

print getUniqueWords(['a','b','c','a','b']);
```

['a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: yea that works thanks ! I voted your answer up and accepted it as the solution

Comment: To make this work for relatively big inputs, it might be better to keep the uniqueWords sorted, using binary search to find the position of the next word to add. I guess that's what is ideally expected in such homeworks, because it reduces the running time quite dramatically if you try to count the unique words for an array with 100000 entries :)

Comment: how would this be implemented I haven't learned about binary searches yet and the professor hasn't stressed efficiency yet.  It's mostly just here is the sample input, i need it to do this, here is the sample output.  I've done somethings recursively before i learned that recursion isn't desired.  however, he didn't care.

Answer (score 2):

I dislike homework problems that (attempt to) require you to choose poor algorithms. Better choices are to use a `set` or a [`trie`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTrie&ei=m0lbUvfPMMr9kAX-zoHgDQ&usg=AFQjCNEIcyShNtanyShhRfB9XU5VqI6VNA&sig2=-J8qUB4hcx6A8Gi3GvWoyA&bvm=bv.53899372,d.dGI) for example.

You can fix your program with 2 small changes

```
def getUniqueWords(allWords):
    uniqueWords = []
    uniqueWords.append(allWords[0])
    for i in range(len(allWords)):
        for j in range(len(uniqueWords)):
            if allWords[i] == uniqueWords[j]:
                break
        else:
            uniqueWords.append(allWords[i])
            print uniqueWords[j]
    print uniqueWords
    return uniqueWords
```

---

first you need to stop looping when you see the word is already present

```
        for j in range(len(uniqueWords)):
            if allWords[i] == uniqueWords[j]:
                break  # break out of the loop since you found a match
```

---

second is to use the `for`/`else` construct instead of `if`/`else`

```
        for j in range(len(uniqueWords)):
            if allWords[i] == uniqueWords[j]:
                break
        else:
            uniqueWords.append(allWords[i])
            print uniqueWords[j]
```

Comment: originally all I did was uniqueWords = set(allWords) and then I did uniqueWords = list(uniqueWords) he also never went over tuples which easily knocked down some of my other assignments from x number lines to like 3 lines.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use collections.Counter class? (especially if you also want to count the number of times every word appears in the source document).

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter

```
import collections.Counter
def getUniqueWords(allWords):
    uniqueWords = Counter()

    for word in allWords:
        uniqueWords[word]+=1
    return uniqueWords.keys()
```

On the other side, if you just want to count the words, just use a set:

```
def getUniqueWords(allWords):
    uniqueWords =set()

    for word in allWords:
        uniqueWords.add(word)
    return uniquewords #if you want to return them as a set
    OR
    return list(uniquewords) #if you want to return a list
```

And if you are restricted to the loops, and the input is relatively big, a loop + binary search is a better alternative than just a loop - something like that:

```
def getUniqueWords(allWords):
   uw = []
   for word in allWords:
       (lo,hi) = (0,len(uw)-1)
       m = -1
       while hi>=lo and m==-1:
           mid = lo + (hi-lo)/2
           if uw[mid]==word:
              m = mid
           elif uw[mid]<word:
              lo = mid+1
           else:
              hi = mid-1
       if m==-1:
           m = lo
           uw = uw[:m]+[word]+uw[m:]
   return uw
```

The difference between using this and a simple loop if your input has about 100000 words is that your PC doesn't make noise while executing the program :)

Comment: I'm restricted to using loops.  I know if I use a set it would make this 1000 times easier but yea.

Comment: I see. Then a sorted list might be the best approach.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the `bisect` module?

Answer (score 1):

You can use set to get unique words:

```
def getUniqueWords(allWords) :
    uniqueWords = list({i for i in allWords})
    return uniqueWords

print getUniqueWords(['a','b','c','a','b']);
```

**Result:**
['c', 'a', 'b']

[image]