# Find unique words in a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of lists that I would like to iterate over using a for loop, and create a new list with only the unique words. This is similar to a [question asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350900/finding-all-unique-words-from-a-list-using-loops/19351121), but I could not get the solution to work for me for **a list within a list**

For example, the nested list is as follows:

`ListofList = [['is', 'and', 'is'], ['so', 'he', 'his'], ['his', 'run']],`

The desired output would be a single list:

`List_Unique = [['is','and','so','he','his','run']]`

---

I have tried the following two variations of code, but the output of all of them is a list of repeats:

```
unique_redundant = [] 
for i in redundant_search:
    redundant_i = [j for j in i if not i in unique_redundant]
    unique_redundant.append(redundant_i)
unique_redundant


unique_redundant = [] 
for list in redundant_search:
    for j in list:
        redundant_j = [i for i in j if not i in unique_redundant]
    unique_redundant.append(length_j)
unique_redundant
```

Example output given for the above two (incorrect) variations

(I ran the code on my real set of data and it gave repeating lists within lists of the same pair of words, though this isn't the actual two words, just an example):

```
List_Unique = [['is','and'],['is','and'],['is','and']]
```

Comment: do you want nested list output or a single list?

Comment: A single list would be what I need. So the unique search is finding unique values across all nested lists, and not just within each

Comment: ok,then there's the answer below check it out

Answer (score 4):

I'd  suggest using the [set() class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) [union()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) in this way:

```
ListofList = [['is', 'and', 'is'], ['so', 'he', 'his'], ['his', 'run']]

set().union(*ListofList)
# => {'run', 'and', 'so', 'is', 'his', 'he'}
```

---

**Explanation**

It works like the following:

```
test_set = set().union([1])
print(test_set)
# => {1}
```

The asterisk operator before the list (`*ListofList`) unpacks the list:

```
lst = [[1], [2], [3]]
print(lst) #=> [[1], [2], [3]]
print(*lst) #=> [1] [2] [3]
```

Comment: This is the only pythonic anwer

Answer (score 2):

First flatten the list with `itertools.chain`, then use `set` to return the unique elements and pass that into a list:

```py
from itertools import chain

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print([{list(chain(*list_of_lists))}])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.chain` to flatten the list and `dict.fromkeys` to keep the unique values in order:

```
ListofList = [['is', 'and', 'is'], ['so', 'he', 'his'], ['his', 'run']]

from itertools import chain
List_Unique = [list(dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(ListofList)))]
```

Comment: my real dataset as some 30k nested lists, so when I try that code it throws the error ```from_iterable() takes exactly one argument (31962 given)``` Any ideas?

Comment: @Brian there was a typo, please check the update

Answer (score 1):

**Just index out nested list with the help of while and acquire all the values in new list `while cnt<len(listoflist)`**

```
ListofList = [['is', 'and', 'is'], ['so', 'he', 'his'], ['his', 'run']]
list_new=[]
cnt=0
while cnt<len(ListofList):
    for i in ListofList[cnt]:
        if i in list_new:
            continue
        else:
            list_new.append(i)
    cnt+=1
print(list_new)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['is', 'and', 'so', 'he', 'his', 'run']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in ListofList for item in sublist]

# use this if order should not change
List_Unique = []
for item in flat_list:
    if item not in List_Unique:
        List_Unique.append(item)


# use this if order is not an issue
# List_Unique = list(set(flat_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
ListofList = [['is', 'and', 'is'], ['so', 'he', 'his'], ['his', 'run']]
uniqueItems = []
for firstList in ListofList:
    for item in firstList:
        if item not in uniqueItems:
            uniqueItems.append(item)
print(uniqueItems)
```

It uses a nested `for` loop to access each item and check whether it is in `uniqueItems`.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

using basic **set** concept, set consists of unique elements

```
lst = [['is', 'and', 'is'], ['so', 'he', 'his'], ['his', 'run']]
new_list = []
for x in lst:
    for y in set(x):
        new_list.append(y)
print(list(set(new_list)))


['run', 'and', 'is', 'so', 'he', 'his']
```